# Typescript function whose return type is union of values in array

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to write a function such that its return type is the union of values of an array.

Something like,

```
function within(values: string[]) {
    return (val: any): <union of values> => {
      if(!values.include(val)) throw new Error('Not allowed')
      return val
    }
}
```

Now `ReturnType<within(['a', 'b'])>` would be `'a' | 'b'`.

Comment: If you want to raise error in compile time you can define union type for some value like: `type Unionvalue = 'a' | 'b';` and use it as return type of your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In complement to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68205062/3388225).

For inline cases you can simplify call semantics using [variadic tuple types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094):

```ts
function within<T extends string[]>(values: readonly [...T]) {
    return (val: unknown) => {
      if(!(values as readonly unknown[]).includes(val)) throw new Error('Not allowed')
      return val as T[number];
    };
}

const arr = ['a', 'b'] as const; // still have to annotate `as const` to prevent widening
const r1 = within(arr)('a'); // type of r is 'a' | 'b'

const r2 = within(['a', 'b'])('b'); // typescript infers readonly automatically; r2 ~ 'a' | 'b'
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nn6kdN)

Answer (score 2):

Make the function generic.

```
function within<T extends Array<string>>(values: T) {
    return (val: unknown) => {
      if(!(values as unknown[]).includes(val)) throw new Error('Not allowed')
      return val as T[number];
    };
}

const arr = ['a', 'b'] as ['a', 'b']; // prevent automatic widening to string[]
const r = within(arr)('a');
// type of r is 'a' | 'b'
```

Note that since [`.includes`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) has type problems, you need to do something to get around it, such as asserting that the `values` is `unknown[]`.

Comment: You can use `assert` function to handle error